# Deleting duplicate lines along with original

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep, tcl

I have a file which contains patterns on each line, some of which are repeating. i want only those patterns which **do not** repeat. So, I want to remove all repeating data along with the original pattern. I cannot use sort since i want the patterns to be in same sequence.

file:

```
foo1  
foo2   
foo3  
foo2  
foo4  
foo1  
foo1  
foo5
```

Desired output:

```
foo3   
foo4  
foo5
```

Since it is a large file (about 1gb), I prefer something very fast. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not like to get anything particularly fast for this task. And you better have lots of RAM.

Comment: You could just load all lines into a hash, where the key is the line content.and value is number of occurrences. Then extract all keys where value equal 1, the unique ones.

Comment: @Kim the issue with that approach is that the order is lost.

Comment: Good point. YOu could add a couter to each key, so it becomes 1:foo1, 2:foo2 . So order is  retained as you can now sort on key. Just need to split out the number section on retrieval.

Comment: @Wintermute I just want an efficient code. : )

Comment: @valuable_asset Well, depending on the length of the lines in your file, you'll need quite a lot of RAM to store the whole file linewise in a hash map (and I do mean **quite** a lot). I encountered that problem a while ago with smaller files and short lines. If you have 4 GB of RAM, you'll have to tackle the problem in a different manner from the way you could use if you had 32 GB.

Comment: @valuable_asset: What is the typical length of the records in your file? Do you need trailing spaces to be ignored, as your example contains varying numbers of space characters?

Comment: How long is the typical line?

Comment: @Borodin. Each line is about 4 characters in length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to walk over the file twice, count how often a line appears the first time and print the unique ones during the second pass as they are encountered.

If you have enough RAM (this will take quite a bit), you can use

```
awk 'NR == FNR { seen[$0]++; next } seen[$0] == 1' file file
```

How much memory this requires depends on the average length of lines in the file. If the lines are very short, the overhead of the hash map will blow the memory usage far beyond the 1GB the pure input data requires. I've recently had a similar use case where **awk ended up using over 8GB of RAM for ~300 MB of input data** where lines were on average ~8 characters long. Rewriting the code in C++ made the problem less severe but remained impractical.

We ended up solving the problem with sqlite, trading speed for RAM. For your use case, this might end up as

```
rm lcount.db
awk -v q=\' '
  NR == 1 {
    print "CREATE TABLE lines (line text PRIMARY KEY, counter INTEGER, nr INTEGER);"
  }
  {
    sub(q, q q);  # hacky way to sanitize lines with quotes in them
    print "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO lines VALUES (" q $0 q ", 0, " NR ");";
    print "UPDATE lines SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE line = " q $0 q ";"
  }
  END {
    print "SELECT line FROM lines WHERE counter = 1 ORDER BY nr;"
  }' file  | sqlite3 lcount.db
```

Surprisingly, this was still reasonably fast. How fast it is depends again on your available RAM -- the sqlite process will only use a few megabytes, but the speed depends largely on the available space for file system caching of the database file.

**I'm not terribly happy with the SQL sanitation, mind you;** I'm not convinced that it is entirely safe if the input data comes from an untrustworthy source. In the event that this is a worry, you can use the following:

```
perl -MDBI -e'
   my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=lcount.db", "", "", { PrintError=>0, RaiseError=>1 });
   $dbh->do("CREATE TABLE lines (line TEXT PRIMARY KEY, counter INTEGER, nr INTEGER)");

   my $ins_sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO lines VALUES (?, 0, ?)");
   my $upd_sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE lines SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE line = ?");
   while (<>) {
      $ins_sth->execute($_, $.);
      $upd_sth->execute($_);
   }

   my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT line FROM lines WHERE counter = 1 ORDER BY nr");
   print while ($_) = $sth->fetchrow_array;
' file
```

Comment: A nice inventive solution!

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{++seen[$0];next}seen[$0]==1' file file
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

It reads the file twice, keeping a total of the number of occurrences of each line the first time round and printing the unique lines the second time.

Another option, which uses more memory but only reads the file once:

```
$ awk '{++seen[$0];a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;++i)if(seen[a[i]]==1)print a[i]}' file
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

This also stores each line in the array `a`, so instead of re-reading the file, a loop can be used to print the unique lines.

I'm not sure how this would work under the hood (I guess that the memory requirements are probably similar) but you could also use a few standard tools:

```
$ sort file | uniq -u | grep -Fxf - file
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

`sort file | uniq -u` obtains the unique lines and passes them to grep as a list of patterns to match. The `-F` switch matches fixed strings and the `-x` means that only lines matching the whole pattern are printed.

Comment: I cannot sort. I require the patterns to be in sequence.

Comment: @valuable_asset the input to `grep` is sorted but the output is not, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This could perform well if there are lots of repeating lines,

```
perl -ne'
  $h{$_}++ or push @r,$_;
  END {
    $h{$_} <2 and print for @r
  }
' file
```

It loops through file and stores count of identical lines in `%h` hash, while populating `@r` array with unique lines. At the end of file processing it loops trough `@r` and prints only lines which occurred less than two times.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution. This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

The data in your question has variable numbers of trailing spaces. I have assumed that you ***don't*** need to trim these before comparing them

1GB isn't so big for a file, and the fastest way to process it is to read it into memory. This solution keeps a hash to establish uniqueness and an array to maintain the order

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (%count, @lines);
$count{$_}++ or push @lines, $_ while <>;
print grep $count{$_} == 1, @lines;
```

**output**

```
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

Answer (score 0):

The core of your problem is this - because you need to delete the original, until you know it's a dupe, you have to hold it in memory until the whole file is parsed.

There are two ways you can fundamentally do this - store the whole thing in memory or read the file twice from disk.

So in perl - reading into memory (will use a *multiple* of the raw filesize, due to overheads).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

open ( my $input_fh, "<", "data_file_name" ) or die $!;
my @data = <$input_fh>; 
close ( $input_fh ):

my %count_of;
$count_of{$_}++ for @data;

foreach my $line ( @data ) {
   print $line if $count_of{$line} <= 1;
}
```

Reading file twice - will take longer, because disk IO, but lower memory usage (depends a bit on just how many duplicates there are).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $input_fh, "<", "data_file_name" ) or die $!;
my %count_of;
$count_of{$_}++ for <$input_fh>;

seek( $input_fh, 0, 0 );    #rewind - could close/reopen instead.
foreach my $line (<$input_fh>) {
    print $line if $count_of{$line} <= 1;
}
close($input_fh);
```

note - in both of the above, we use the line literally - including whitespace and linefeeds. So: `"foo   "` and `"foo"` will be considered different. You can deal with that quite easily with a "sed like" search and replaced, etc. `s/\s+//g` to remove whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of solving this in Tcl is to use dictionaries, as they preserve the order of insertion of keys. In particular `dict incr` and `dict for` are very useful. As a stdin→stdout filter…

```
set seen {}
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    dict incr seen $line
}
dict for {line count} $seen {
    if {$count == 1} {
        puts $line
    }
}
```

This will use memory proportional to the number of *different* lines, and will read the input exactly once; it's going to be very difficult to do satisfy the problem requirements in less, as there could be an arbitrary number of lines to read before finding a duplicate for a line.